# Modify a value by function call if its key ends with a specific word

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, reference, key

I need to change all the values for a matching key within an associative array using php but I can only target the key by matching a specific string within the key and not the entire key name as it may change.

In the case below, I need a way to target all the "_file" keys and change their filenames to a related attachment ID but targeting the entire key "bg_infographic_file" won't be possible as the key may change to "bg_whitepaper_file" or some other name.

Current $resources array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bg_infographic_title] => Logo Upload
            [bg_infographic_file] => logomark-large-forVector.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bg_infographic_title] => Profile Image
            [bg_infographic_file] => ProfilePic.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bg_infographic_title] => Document Upload
            [bg_infographic_file] => Test_PDF.pdf
        )

)
```

What I need as a result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [bg_infographic_title] => Logo Upload
            [bg_infographic_file] => 86390
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [bg_infographic_title] => Profile Image
            [bg_infographic_file] => 99350
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [bg_infographic_title] => Document Upload
            [bg_infographic_file] => 67902
        )

)
```

I'm thinking of something along these lines but I can't quite figure it out as the following simply returns the unchanged array data:

```
foreach( $resources as $key=>$value ) {
    if( strpos($key, '_file') !== FALSE ) {
        $value = get_image_id_from_url($value);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: your doing nothing to change the array - so um what do you want to happen?

Comment: Why don't you change `if( strpos($key, '_file') !== FALSE )` to `if(strpos($key, '_file'))`

Comment: Sam... because it is technically possible that the substring could exist anywhere in the key string and not necessarily at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this, instead:

```
foreach ($resources as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue) {
        if (substr($subKey, -5) == '_file') {
            $resources[$key][$subKey] = get_image_id_from_url($subValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The first issue is that you have an array of arrays, and you were only looping through the outer array. The second issue is that `$value` can't be modified inside the `foreach()` loop in this way. We can also use `substr($key, -5) == '_file'` to make sure `'_file'` is at the end of the string.

Comment: print_r($resources) is still returning the original array after your recommended foreach loop.

Comment: That broke the page for some reason.

Comment: Awesome, no problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$findMe = "_file";
foreach ($resources as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $findInMe => $fileName) {
        $pos = strpos($findInMe, $findMe);
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $resources[$key][$findInMe] = get_image_id_from_url($fileName);
        }
    }
}
```